# Declared Activity Not Starting When Called

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, crash

I am at my wits end.  I am developing an application for my fire department and have a, probably glaring, error that I can not find.  I am trying to start a second activity from my first activity and the application fails.  Logcat asks if I have declared my activity, and I have.

Here is my manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name="com.HCFD.scenenotes.BrushNotes" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.HCFD.scenenotes.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">"
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

And here is the intent:

```
Intent openBrushNotes = new Intent(this, BrushNotes.class);
```

And here is the call where my app crashes:

```
public void openNewNotes(int a){
    Log.i(TAG, "Open New Notes from button " + a);
    switch(a){
    case 1:
        startActivity(openBrushNotes);
        break;
```

Can someone point me in the right direction as to what I am obviously missing?  If it matters I am developing on Eclipse ADT under windows 8.1

My entire BrushNotes as of now:

```
package com.HCFD.scenenotes;
```

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

```
public class BrushNotes extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle brushBundle) {
    super.onCreate(brushBundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.brush_notes);


}

}
```

Logcat:

```
06-21 18:58:19.997: E/AndroidRuntime(21305): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-21 18:58:19.997: E/AndroidRuntime(21305): Process: com.HCFD.scenenotes, PID: 21305
06-21 18:58:19.997: E/AndroidRuntime(21305): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:   Unable to find explicit activity class {/com.HCFD.scenenotes.BrushNotes}; have you declared   this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
06-21 18:58:19.997: E/AndroidRuntime(21305):    at  android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1648)
06-21 18:58:19.997: E/AndroidRuntime(21305):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1442)
06-21 18:58:19.997: E/AndroidRuntime(21305):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3474)
06-21 18:58:19.997: E/AndroidRuntime(21305):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3435)
06-21 18:58:19.997: E/AndroidRuntime(21305):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3677)
06-21 18:58:19.997: E/AndroidRuntime(21305):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3645)
06-21 18:58:19.997: E/AndroidRuntime(21305):    at com.HCFD.scenenotes.MainActivity.openNewNotes(MainActivity.java:146)
06-21 18:58:19.997: E/AndroidRuntime(21305):    at com.HCFD.scenenotes.MainActivity$2$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:125)
06-21 18:58:19.997: E/AndroidRuntime(21305):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:167)
06-21 18:58:19.997: E/AndroidRuntime(21305):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-21 18:58:19.997: E/AndroidRuntime(21305):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
06-21 18:58:19.997: E/AndroidRuntime(21305):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
06-21 18:58:19.997: E/AndroidRuntime(21305):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-21 18:58:19.997: E/AndroidRuntime(21305):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-21 18:58:19.997: E/AndroidRuntime(21305):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
06-21 18:58:19.997: E/AndroidRuntime(21305):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
06-21 18:58:19.997: E/AndroidRuntime(21305):    at        dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Would you post the logcat? Just to make sure, does `BrushNotes` extends `Activity` and is in the package `com.HCFD.scenenotes`?

Comment: Logcat is posted.  I have also checked to make sure I didnt omit extends Activity.

Comment: Found it.  I declared the Intent in the wrong place.  I had it above the onCreate method.  I have now moved it to inside the case 1: and changed the context from this to MainActivity.this